# Java Applet puzzle picture game

Tags: java, applet

I am making a java sliding puzzle for my project, and i have managed to crop the images and making it move to a blank space, however i am still puzzled on how to know whether the user got the correct solution or not. i wanted to congratulate the user when he gets the correct pattern.

```
 import java.applet.*; 
 import java.util.*;
 import java.awt.*; 
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.image.*;


 public class SlidePuzz extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener,MouseListener {
 int gridDim = 3;
 int animal = -1;
 int pieceDim = 0;
 int a; int b;
 int gapX = -1; int gapY = -1;
 int moveX = -1; int moveY = -1;
 Image[][] pieces = new Image[7][7];
 int[][] placement = new int[7][7];
 String [] images = {"mouse","cat","dog"};

 String stage = "grid";
 Image img;


  public void init() {
  setSize(420, 420);
  addMouseMotionListener(this);
  addMouseListener(this);
  }

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
 if(stage=="grid") {
 g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
 g.fillRect(0,0,60*gridDim,60*gridDim);

 g.setColor(Color.white);
 g.fillRect(60*gridDim,0,(7-gridDim)*60,420);
 g.fillRect(0,60*gridDim,60*gridDim,(7-gridDim)*60);

 g.setColor(Color.black);

 for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {
  g.drawLine(i*60,0,i*60,460);
  g.drawLine(0,i*60,460,i*60);
 }

  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.fillRect(120,0,180,20);

  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.drawString("click to choose "+gridDim+"x"+gridDim+" grid", 145, 15);
  } else if (stage=="animal") {
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.fillRect(0,0,420,420);

  g.setColor(Color.black);    
  g.drawString("Please click an animal...", 80, 100);
  g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD,  22));
  g.drawString("Mouse", 80, 150);
  g.drawString("Cat", 80, 200);
  g.drawString("Dog", 80, 250);
  } else if (stage=="game") {


  if (gapX<0) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,420,420);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN,  12));
    g.drawString("Loading image...", 120, 50);

    tr = new MediaTracker(this);
    img = getImage(getCodeBase(),  images[animal]+".jpg");
    tr.addImage(img,0);


    for(int x=0; x<gridDim; x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<gridDim; y++) {
        pieces[x][y] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(img.getSource(),
            new CropImageFilter(x*pieceDim, y*pieceDim, pieceDim, pieceDim)));
    placement[x][y] = (x==gridDim-1 && y==gridDim-1) ? -2 : -1;
    tr.addImage(pieces[x][y],0);
  }
}


    Random r = new Random();
    Boolean placed;
    for(int x=0; x<gridDim; x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<gridDim; y++) {
    // if its the gap, no need to draw anything
    if (placement[x][y]==-2) break;

    // keep looping until piece is selected thats not already drawn
    do {
      do {
        a = r.nextInt(gridDim);
        b = r.nextInt(gridDim);
      } while (a==gridDim-1 && b==gridDim-1);
      placed = false;
      for(int c=0; c<gridDim; c++) {
        for(int d=0; d<gridDim; d++) {
          if(placement[c][d]==a*10+b) placed=true;
        }
      }
    } while (placed);

    // draw on the screen and record what's gone here
    g.drawImage(pieces[a][b], x*pieceDim, y*pieceDim, this);
    placement[x][y] = a*10+b;
      }
    }
    // record where the gap is
    gapX = gridDim-1; gapY = gridDim-1;

  // a piece needs to be moved
  } else if (moveX>=0){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(moveX*pieceDim, moveY*pieceDim, pieceDim, pieceDim);

    b = placement[moveX][moveY]%10;
    a = (placement[moveX][moveY]-b)/10;

    g.drawImage(pieces[a][b], gapX*pieceDim, gapY*pieceDim, this);
    placement[gapX][gapY] = a*10+b;
    placement[moveX][moveY] = -2;
    gapX = moveX; gapY = moveY;
    moveX = -1; moveY = -1;


  } else {
    for(int x=0; x<gridDim; x++) {
      for(int y=0; y<gridDim; y++) {
    if (placement[x][y]==-2) continue;
    b = placement[x][y]%10;
    a = (placement[x][y]-b)/10;
    g.drawImage(pieces[a][b], x*pieceDim, y*pieceDim, this);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
 if(stage=="grid") {
  int mousePos = me.getX()>me.getY() ? me.getX() : me.getY();
  int oldGridSize = gridDim;

  gridDim = (mousePos/60)+1;

  if(gridDim<3) gridDim=3;
  if (gridDim!=oldGridSize) repaint();
  }
  }

 public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
  int x = me.getX();
  int y = me.getY();
  if(stage=="grid") {
  stage = "animal";
  repaint();
   } else if(stage=="animal") {
    if(x<150 && x>80 && y<150 && y>130) animal=0;
    else if(x<150 && x>80 && y<200 && y>180) animal=1;
    else if(x<150 && x>80 && y<250 && y>130) animal=2;
    if (animal>-1) {
    stage="game";
    pieceDim = 420/gridDim;
    repaint();
   }
  } else if(stage=="game") {
  x /= pieceDim;
  y /= pieceDim;

  Boolean right = (x-1==gapX && y==gapY);
  Boolean left = (x+1==gapX && y==gapY);
  Boolean down = (x==gapX && y-1==gapY);
  Boolean up = (x==gapX && y+1==gapY);
  if (right || left || down || up) {
    moveX = x;
    moveY = y;
    repaint();
  }
  }
  }

 public void update(Graphics g) { paint(g); }

 public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent me) {}
 public void mouseExited (MouseEvent me) {}
 public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me) {}
 public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {}
 public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {}
 }
```

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ...

Comment: ... 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).